# Firebase - Sending FCM Post to a single device in a specific topic

Tags: firebase, xamarin, xamarin.forms, firebase-cloud-messaging, cordova-plugin-fcm

I'm using Xamarin and Firebase Cloud Messaging to send push notifications to mobile devices.

I have notification settings where the user can allow and block specific notification types. So I made topics A, B, C for example. If the user allows notifications of type A, then the device will subscribe to topic A. I want to send a unique notification to that device if it is subscribed to notifications of type A. However, it seems that I cannot add two parameters to 'to: '

Currently I have:

```
{
"to": "{device_token}",
"data": {
"message": "hello",
},
"priority": "high"
}
```

I tried to add `"condition": 'A' in topics` but it doesn't allow me to have both 'to' and 'condition'.

Comment: Not allowing `to` and `condition` together is a restriction in FCM -- so that part is expected. Based on your use-case, just keep your `condition` parameter and it should work. Cheers!

Comment: If I keep my condition parameter, it would send to every device in topic A. I want to send to a specific device in topic A

Comment: A specific device in topic A. So basically just that one. If you already have the token, then you don't need to specify the topic.

Comment: Yes but if the device isn't subscribed to topic A, then it shouldn't receive the notification. So basically

if {device_token} exists in topic A, send notification. 
else, don't.

Comment: I have a notification settings page, where there are 3 switches. If user toggles switch 1, it would subscribe to topic A, and therefore user wants notifications based on topic A. If user toggles topic A off, user unsubscribes from topic A and therefore doesn't want notifications from this topic. These notifications are unique to each device, so I cannot send a global notification to all devices in topic A

Answer (score 0):

You can't combine topics and tokens in the way you're trying. If you send a message to a topic, the message is delivered to every instance that is subscribed to that topic. If you send a message to a device token, it is only delivered to that device.

Some options I can think of:

- Send a data message, and then detect in the client whether to show it or not.
- Build your own message targeting system on top of device instance IDs.

Comment: I'm using https://github.com/CrossGeeks/FirebasePushNotificationPlugin

There seems to be no solution to detect the notification BEFORE it is displayed to the user. I can only see onNotificationOpened and onNotificationReceived (both are fired after the notification is displayed to the user)

Comment: Check the documentation here: https://github.com/CrossGeeks/FirebasePushNotificationPlugin/blob/master/docs/FirebaseNotifications.md. It talks about message types, with data messages being the type I refer to in my answer. So it seems the product knows about the message type, although I don't immediately see what method in their API will get invoked for data messages.

Comment: I see, there is still no way to prevent a data message from being displayed on the device once it has been sent (as far as I can see)

Comment: "With FCM, you can send two types of messages to clients:

Notification messages, sometimes thought of as "display messages." These are handled by the FCM SDK automatically. **Data messages, which are handled by the client app.**"